# Calculating numbers from an external file from my project (Project Euler #13)

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to find multiple ways to solve Project Euler's [problem #13](http://projecteuler.net/problem=13). I've already got it solved two different ways, but what I am trying to do this time is to have my solution read from a text file that contains all of the numbers, from there it converts it and adds the column numbers farthest to the right. I also want to solve this problem in a way such that if we were to add new numbers to our list, the list can contain any amount of rows or columns, so it's length is not predefined (non array? I'm not sure if a jagged array would apply properly here since it can't be predefined).

So far I've got:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> sum = new List<int>();

        string bigIntFile = @"C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\BigNumbers.txt";

        
        string result;
    
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(bigIntFile);

        while ((result = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                int converted = Convert.ToInt32(result.Substring(i, 1));
                sum.Add(converted);
            }
        }

    }
```

which reads the file and converts each character from the string to a single int. I'm trying to think how I can store that int in a collection that is like 2D array, but the collection needs to be versatile and store any # of rows / columns. Any ideas on how to store these digits other than just a basic list? Is there maybe a way I can set up a list so it's like a 2D array that is not predefined? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Also I don't want to use "BigInteger". That'd be a little too easy to read the line, convert the string to a BigInt, store it in a BigInt list and then sum up all the integers from there.

Comment: I think that would work, yes. But any Idea how to add columns from it? I want to be able to add the Converted characters to List<List<int>>, and add the right most column. Long hand Addition is what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no resizable 2D collection built into the .NET framework. I'd just go with the "jagged arrays" type of data structure, just with lists:

```
List<List<int>>
```

You can also vary this pattern by using an array for each row:

```
List<int[]>
```

If you want to read the file a little simpler, here is how:

```
List<int[]> numbers =
 File.EnumerateLines(path)
 .Select(lineStr => lineStr.Select(@char => @char - '0').ToArray())
 .ToList();
```

Far less code. You can reuse a lot of built-in stuff to do basic data transformations. That gives you less code to write and to maintain. It is more extensible and it is less prone to bugs.

If you want to select a column from this structure, do it like this:

```
int colIndex = ...;
int[] column = numbers.Select(row => row[index]).ToArray();
```

You can encapsulate this line into a helper method to remove noise from your main addition algorithm.

Note, that the efficiency of all those patterns is *far* less than a 2D array, but in your case it is good enough.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I am looking for! Thank you. ♥ StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can simply use an 2D array, since you actually do know in advance its dimensions: 100 x 50.

If for some reason you want to solve a more general problem, you may indeed use a List of Lists, List>.

having said that, I wonder: are you actually trying to sum up all the numbers? if so, I would suggest another approach: consider just which section part of the 50 digit numbers actually influences the first digits of their sum. Hint: you don't need the entire number.

Comment: Well I know the array is 100x50, but I don't want a pre-defined collection like an array. I think the problem is just my lack of knowledge on how to use List<List<>>.

Comment: Please consider my other suggestion.

Comment: Well I want to sum all of the numbers. Pretty much I want to use long hand addition but write it in code. Add the right most column, take the the ones place, place it below the entire addition table and carry over the remainder of what is left to the left most column.

Comment: You do not have to sum up the entire number! :-) You can do this brute force, but with a little tweak, without resorting to column addition.

Comment: Consider the following

1234 + 1523 = 2757, 54781234 + 54781523 = 109562757

look at the first 4 digits. You can see that although the numbers are a lot bigger, the only thing that matters for the first 4 digits of the sum are the first 4 digits of each number!

Comment: @Vitaly It's not quite that easy. If you have enough numbers, a carry can propagate quite far. You need to use a couple more digits than you want and then check whether a carry may change the desired digits. If it could (rare, if you use say four or five digits more than desired), you need to consider more digits. But the idea is good, if you don't want to use big integers or string addition.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed the carry can propagate quite far. I am not sure I agree that you actually need to take it under account though. I don't really care about carries since it affects digits that are beyond the scope I am interested in. (i am only interested in carries that settle down somewhere in the first 10 digits)

Comment: Vitaly, if you are interested in the first four digits of the sum, and the result of adding the first four digits of 100 numbers is 234999, are the first four digits of the sum of the entire numbers 2349 or 2350? Similarly if you sum the first five, six, ... digits. If the sum ends with all 9s, you have a problem.

Comment: Oh crap, I mixed up last and first... however since there are 100 numbers, a carry can travel only so far. you need to calculate the amount of numbers that can be cut off. Ill give it some more thought. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: I believe it is 3. So the first 13 digits of each number should be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Consider the arrangement where one number has first digit 1, the others all have first digit 2, then for the following digits, in each place one number has a 9, all the others 0. Then your sum becomes 199.... and you must check all digits to see whether a carry is generated anywhere. But such cases are very rare, and if you start with the first 13 (I'd take 15 to make the possibly required checking all that much more unlikely), you can see whether a carry-in from the following digits might influence the first ten, if so sum the next block.